# Screens tilt left when I use the super key OR 9 dot apps button

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display

I have two Dell 22 inch screens - they are set up 1 landscape (VGA) and 1 portrait (Display Port).  Ubuntu 17.10

Output from `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2730 x 1680, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1048x1680+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 470mm x 300mm
   1048x1680     59.86*+
XWAYLAND1 connected 1680x1050+0+234 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 470mm x 300mm
   1680x1050     59.85*+
```

Relevant Output from `lspci`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

Whenever I use the super key to search OR click the 9 dot apps button in the dock BOTH screens tilt left, but also the writing gets blurred. If I then press escape, (i.e. get out of apps or search mode), it all goes back to normal.

I have added two pics to show before and after hitting the super key.

[image: Before]

[image: After hitting the super key]

Sorry about the image quality, my HTC One M7 phone camera is a bit shot.

I have tried swapping the VGA and display port connectors, (both monitors can do VGA and display port), and swapping monitor 1 and 2 landscape vs portrait, but it all still tilts when I press the super key.

Should I try and disable WAYLAND?

One more thing, I *think* it was doing this before I upgraded to 17.10, but I can't quite remember that far back.  :-)

If I can't find a resolution I may switch to both being landscape, but I have been using them this way on windows and ubuntu for so long (5+ years), it would feel weird going back. And also, it's clearly a bug and I'm sure *someone* must be having the same issue...

Comment: Yeah, switching back to Xorg from Wayland sounds like a good idea in your case.